# Google Maps Javascript Api V3 data.remove isn't removing a feature

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a little pet project to edit personal maps by drawing polygons and am finding that when I call map.data.remove(feature), the feature is removed from map.data but isn't removed from the visual map.  Some of the javascript that doesn't relate to the data layer has been omitted.  What additional steps, removal, or function calls do I need to actually remove the feature from the map as well?

```
...
function CustomMapType() {
}
CustomMapType.prototype.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);
CustomMapType.prototype.maxZoom = 7;
CustomMapType.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
    var baseURL = 'static/tiles/images/';
    var x = ((coord.x % Math.pow(2, zoom))
        + Math.pow(2, zoom)) % Math.pow(2, zoom);
    baseURL += zoom + '_' + x + '_' + coord.y + '.png';
    div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
    div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#1B2D33';
    div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + baseURL + ')';
    return div;
};

CustomMapType.prototype.name = "Custom";
CustomMapType.prototype.alt = "Tile Coordinate Map Type";

var map;
var CustomMapType = new CustomMapType();


//////////     Initializer Functions     //////////

function initialize() {
  var styledMapOptions = { name: "Custom Style" };
  var mapOptions = getMapOptions();
  var data = getDataObject();

  data.addListener("click", function(event) {
    fillFormFromFeature(event.feature);
  });

  data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    var style = featureStyles[feature.getProperty('style')];
    return style
  });


  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  data.setMap(map);

  map.mapTypes.set('custom',CustomMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('custom');
  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID);
}

function getMapOptions() {
  return {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 7,
    isPng: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapMaker: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(65.07,-56.08),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: ['custom', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP],
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
  };
}

function getDataObject() {
  return new google.maps.Data({
    controlPosition: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    controls: ["Point", "Polygon"],
    featureFactory: function(featureGeometry) {
      var date = new Date();
      // TODO add code here for forming polygons.
      var feature = new google.maps.Data.Feature({
        geometry: featureGeometry,
        id: date.getTime(),
        properties: {
          'name': 'none',
          'style': 'new',
          'feature_type': 'new',
          'zIndex': '5000',
        }
      });

      document.forms["feature_form"]["feature_id"].value = feature.getId();

      map.data.add(feature);
      map.data.revertStyle();
      return feature;
    }
  });
}


...
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling `data.remove`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses 2 different `google.maps.Data`-instances.

1. the instance returned by `getDataObject()`
2. the built-in `data`-property of the `Map`-instance

When you create a polygon(or another feature)

1. the feature will be automatically added by the `featureFactory` to the instance returned by `getDataObject()`
2. the call of `map.data.add(feature);` adds the feature also to `map.data`

The result: you have 2 duplicate features, when you call `map.data.remove` you only remove the feature of `map.data`.

Solution: you don't need to add the feature on your own, it will be added automatically. But it's not a feature of `map.data`, it's a feature of the Data-instance returned by `getDataObject`, so you must call the method `remove` of this `Data`-instance:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = getMapOptions();
  var data = getDataObject();

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  data.setMap(map);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(document.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0]);


}

function getMapOptions() {
  return {
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 7,
    isPng: true,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapMaker: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(65.07, -56.08),
    zoom: 3
  };
}

function getDataObject() {
  //create a variable to be able to access it from within
  //the featureFactory
  var Data = new google.maps.Data({
    controlPosition: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    controls: ["Point", "Polygon"],
    featureFactory: function(featureGeometry) {

      var date = new Date();
      // TODO add code here for forming polygons.
      var feature = new google.maps.Data.Feature({
        geometry: featureGeometry,
        id: date.getTime(),
        properties: {
          'name': 'none',
          'style': 'new',
          'feature_type': 'new',
          'zIndex': '5000',
        }
      });

      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      listItem.textContent = [featureGeometry.getType(), feature.getId()].join(' ');
      document.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0].appendChild(listItem);
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(listItem, 'click', function() {
        //remove the feature
        Data.remove(feature);
          //remove the listItem
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this)
      });

      map.data.revertStyle();
      return feature;
    }
  });
  return Data;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
ul {
  background: #fff;
}
li {
  padding-right: 12px;list-style-image:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Delete-silk.png);
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46362880/remove-previously-drawn-shape-from-map-and-geojson?noredirect=1#comment79692715_46362880

Answer (score 0):

For removing a polygon from a map you must set :

```
 yourPolygon.setMap(null);
```

ps: a minor in your code is show  two time the `getDataObject` function

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited the post for clarity.  I'm using features rather than polygons and features don't have a 'setMap' method.